# How to change the size of a Silverlight object in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have implemented a photo gallery in a asp website. The code looks like this:

```
object id="SilverlightObject" data="data:applicaation/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" class="obiect">
param name="source" value="ClientBin/galery.xap"
```

I need to change the object size dynamically from the `aspx.cs` code page on a certain condition, but I can't access the object (something like `if(a>b) then object.height=500`).

Answer (score 0):

You need a `runat="server"` attribute on the tag for it to be accessible from the server code. You then use the id of the element, not the tag name:

```
SilverlightObject.Height = 500;
```

Comment: I already tried that but the next error occurred: An object tag must contain a Class, ClassID or ProgID attribute.

Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel: I see, the `runat="server"` transforms the tag to a server side object, which is created on the server side, so that's not what you want. So, as you can't access the object tag from the server code, the simplest solution would probably be to create the object tag from the server code as a string and put it in a literal tag or a placeholder tag.